# How to print CHEQUE without background in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress-wpf

i would like to print the cheque so i am taking one background image to put the textblocks on correct place so that the text should be on correct place my requirement is i have to put the cheque in the printer and i have to show the values on cheque so my intention is after printing it should not show the image on cheque
[cheque](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sZKo.jpg)

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            dialog.PrintVisual(stackPrinting, "stackPrinting");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code behind button click should be like this hope it works.

```
grdCheque.Background = new SolidColorBrush();
        PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            dialog.PrintVisual(grdCheque, "grdCheque");
            this.Close();
        }
```